# IE 9-10 and Edge not saving cookie during 403 redirect

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, caching, cookies, p3p

I have been trying to figure this out all day. I have an one application that forwards to another application in order to handle logins. The first application redirects to a webAPI URL. That url then takes one of the parameters and creates a token. It then sends a 403 response with a Set-Cookie Header. The cookie that is sent is that header is never being set.

After a bunch of research I thought that It might need a P#P header so I have tried various combinations of that.

Here is the Code:

```
    Public Function Authenticate(t As String, forwardURL As String) As HttpResponseMessage
        Dim resp As New HttpResponseMessage()
        If VestigoBusinessObjects.UserToken.IsValid(t, EncType.AES) Then
            Dim user As New UserToken(t, EncType.AES)
            user.ResetExperation()
            'Create usertoken cookie
            Dim Cookie = New CookieHeaderValue("t", user.GetEncTicket())
            Cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1)
            Cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host
            Cookie.Path = "/"

            resp.Headers.AddCookies(New CookieHeaderValue() {Cookie})
            resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod
            resp.Headers.Location = New Uri(forwardURL)
            resp.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache")
            resp.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache")

            Return resp
        End If
        resp.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized

        Return resp
    End Function
```

Here are the headers that I see being set back in the browser:

Request URL:deleted because it won't let me post them?

t=bB%2B%2FpRLq%2BzobRcXgQuw5rjMa8Yeb1Wxb7qIZCtjLfwiN8RNT%2BQYjzIuWI9j3JPn4qnpXpgK%2F%2B6ucL96lBmpD6ryIbFJvP3yPOfJjXuZsECfWlj58etczEco79q0SNJj0c%2BwKLREh5FWMfTvN%2BQxSn8nMEr6JzS06CuPizM1k0Kef52ZrHVkxHDv6qVyGLJrxRFebwbpFT0LNMCCihJ%2BZ%2FbmfvvKl9lfg18vHT8nhL1dDtAlR0Fd%2FdSuB5L6Yg3Yj%3F%3FHKZNy0zYBTVwdL7NXMFGXw%3D%3D&forwardurl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4644%2FInternalMonitor.html

Request Method:GET

Status Code:303 See Other

Remote Address:[::1]:4644

**Response Headers**

Cache-Control:no-cache

Content-Length:0

Date:Tue, 29 Nov 2016 22:58:11 GMT

Location:deleted because it won't let me post them

P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR IVAi IVDi OUR TST"

Pragma:no-cache

Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0

Set-Cookie:t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expires=Wed, 30 Nov 2016 22:58:12 GMT; domain=localhost; path=/

X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319

X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?

YzpcVEZTXFZlc3RpZ29cVGVzdFxDZW50cmFsTW9uaXRvclxhcGlcQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb25Db250cm9s

bGVyXEF1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZQ==?=

**Request Headers**

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.
8

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br

Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8

Cache-Control:no-cache

Connection:keep-alive

Cookie:ASP.NET_SessionId=cnru1r4g0svzeomwglkwestw; .ASPXAUTH=1566301093F4FC41F147432F8A4B044E3A19EFC46C47A1BE54F95A98E08EE8952197E5212230F0416776480CA3496036DCA0C0B8AEF0D08675D4B20E655E107F055E1D60150BF84334F65FE63E134B0252EF3B8F02E1E0BC372DBA80006300215AAE095F4333F48BB04D0DF315D825BF1A1B0F27A81E32E82ACEEA791BF11551A8F96A1B0AED9EC11EEA5EF34AE03406; hoursDiffGMTTime=-5; ScreenResolution=1920x1080; BrowserResolution=1920x950; t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

Host:localhost:4644

Pragma:no-cache

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36

**Query String Parameters**

t:bB+/pRLq+zobRcXgQuw5rjMa8Yeb1Wxb7qIZCtjLfwiN8RNT+QYjzIuWI9j3JPn4qnpXpgK/+6ucL96lBmpD6ryIbFJvP3yPOfJjXuZsECfWlj58etczEco79q0SNJj0c+wKLREh5FWMfTvN+QxSn8nMEr6JzS06CuPizM1k0Kef52ZrHVkxHDv6qVyGLJrxRFebwbpFT0LNMCCihJ+Z/bmfvvKl9lfg18vHT8nhL1dDtAlR0Fd/dSuB5L6Yg3Yj??HKZNy0zYBTVwdL7NXMFGXw==
forwardurl: deleted because it won't let me post them

Any input would really be appreciated.

Comment: MSIE browsers have a same origin policy and there are IE security zone settings for "Prevent navigation between zones of lower integrity"...without a sample to test you could try.... 1. find out which IE security zones your test environment maps to (File>Properties menu). You should target the Internet zone for public access websites. Also to record console security messages go Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages"...the port number in your url's indicates that you are using the VS IIS express? Publish to a localhost domain first before testing.

Comment: So the zones register as Local intranet | Protected Mode: Off. I tried the trick to log other console messages and it still isn't giving me any kind of error or warning about the redirect. I appreciate the help. If you have any ideas please let me know.